# Detecting Chrome OS with Javascript

Tags: javascript, user-agent, google-chrome-os

I want to detect Chrome OS with Javascript, and I'm using `navigator.userAgent` for this. Now, I'm running Chrome OS, and my navigator userAgent is

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS armv7l 6680.78.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.102 Safari/537.36
```

Now. I used Regular Expressions to check for the style of the userAgent, and wrote the code below.

```
<script>
    if ( navigator.userAgent = /^Mozilla\/\d{1}^.\d{1}^(X11; CrOS i\d{3} \d{1}^.\d{2}\d{3} ^AppleWebKit\/\d{3}^.\d{2} ^(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/ \d{2}^.\d{1}^.\d{3}^.\d{2} ^Safari\/\d{3}^\d{2}/ ){
      console.log(navigator.userAgent);
    } else {
      console.log(navigator.userAgent);
    }
</script>
```

Now, upon loading this Script, I get an error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^Mozilla\/\d{1}^.\d{1}^(X11; CrOS i\d{3} \d{1}^.\d{2}\d{3} ^AppleWebKit\/\d{3}^.\d{2} ^(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/ \d{2}^.\d{1}^.\d{3}^.\d{2} ^Safari\/\d{3}^\d{2}/: Unterminated group
```

What is wrong here with my code?

Comment: Before you write more code that looks at the user agent, you might want to consider using [feature detection](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/not_browser_detect.html) instead.  We, of course, could only help you with feature detection if you described the actual problem you're trying to solve with Chrome OS.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you for the advise, of using feature detection, and I'm sure I'll be using that link later on, but for this web application, I would rather look at the user agent.

Comment: Why do you think user agent detection is better?

Comment: @jfriend00 I think so because Chrome OS is essentially just the Chrome Browser. I want to detect the OS, and not the browser type. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Until you tell us why you're trying to detect Chrome OS (e.g. what the real problem is here), we can't really have a meaningful conversation about using feature detection instead.  You're asking about a particular solution you've selected rather than telling us the real problem you're trying to solve which is a common way people limit themselves here on SO.

Comment: @jfriend00 Proprietary applications. Maybe he is trying to make the next Google. Do you want chunk of that?  The q is useful for me.....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What it's complaining about is that you have an `(` with no matching `)`. In a regular expression, `(` and `)` define *capture groups* and have to be balanced. If you want to match an actual `(` or `)`, you have to escape it with a backslash.

But there are several other issues. It doesn't make sense to have `^` ("beginning of input") anywhere but the beginning of the expression, for instance.

But I don't think anything else puts `CrOS` in the user agent, so perhaps simply:

```
if (/\bCrOS\b/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    // yes, it is (probably, if no one's mucked about with their user agent string)
} else {
    // No, it isn't (probably, if no one's mucked about with their user agent string)
}
```

The `\b` are "word boundaries" so we don't match that string in the middle of a word. Note that I left it case-sensitive.

---

Side note: I find https://regex101.com/#javascript (which I am not in any way affiliated with) quite useful for debugging regular expressions.

Side note #2: The above is useful if you **really do** need to detect ChromeOS, but if it's just a feature you need to check for, as [jfriend00 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657165/detecting-chrome-os-with-javascript/29657232#comment47454028_29657165), feature detection may be the better way to go.

Comment: Thank you for a very explained answer to my question, plus links that I had never even seen before. I will prefer to go with user agent, than feature detection for this time.

Answer (score 7):

How about this?

```
var chromeOS = /(CrOS)/.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

Because a Chrome OS user agent looks like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS i686 0.12.433) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.77 Safari/534.30
```

And filtering out "CrOS" is a good solution.

Comment: What is the g standing for, and what is it used for in your example?

Comment: It's a global modifier, finding all matches and not just the first one. But I guess it can be removed here, see my edited answer.

Comment: There's also no purpose to using a capture group if you're going to use `.test`.

Answer (score 4):

**I Use This:**

It's pretty simple and you can avoid regex.  You could add more agents if you wanted to.

```
// Detect if the OS is Windows or Chrome OS

var detectedOS;

if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows") != -1) {detectedOS = "Windows";}
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("CrOS") != -1) {detectedOS = "Chrome";}

alert("detectedOS: " + detectedOS);
```