# Google chrome identification popup

Tags: javascript, html

I have this line of Javascript:

```
if (true){ 
  $('#custom-tag').html('HTML');
} 
else {
  $('#custom-tag').html('DifferentHTML');
}
```

If a variable is yes, it will run this html code at startup. 
If the variable is not yes, then it will run this line of html at startup.
How can I do this?

EDIT: I'm afraid I forgot to say, I was wanting this to detect your browser. If using chrome, it will put out no HTML. If using other browsers than chrome, it will put out HTML.

EDIT#2: I have this code. I need to fix this for the popup that identifies if it's chrome.

```js
   $(function() {

     $('#in').on('keyup', function() {
       validate();
     });

   });

   function validate() {
     var x = $('#in').val();

     if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {
       $('#result').html('<h3>Chrome</h3>');
     } else {
       $('#result').html('');
     }

   }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="in" onChange="validate()" />

<div id="result">





  <div id="popup" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
      <h2>Browser</h2>
      <a class="close" href="javascript:popupClose();">×</a>
      <div class="content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Just need to connect all of these. EDIT: I need to add the last line of html into the java code if it's not chrome.

Comment: Please be more specific about what `variable checked` means

Comment: I am not understanding your question .. I know it is about the conditional ...  What EXACTLY do you mean by `variable is not checked yes` and `at startup`?

Comment: @Akidus, Check my answer for variable / checkbox condition

Answer (score 1):

Try the one line snippet which use `ternary operator`.

```
// Check if not chrome
if(!$.browser.chrome){
    // If its variable.
    $('#custom-tag').html( (variable == 'yes') ? 'html' : 'different html' );
}

// If its checkbox.
$('#custom-tag').html( $('#checkboxId').is(":checked") ? 'html' : 'different html' );
```

Comment: I think this is close. I need it to detect browsers though. I made an edit.

Comment: Check the answer which has chrome browser check

Comment: There isn't any checks, I need to edit that... Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It might work, I'm trying to add it to my code. I'm learning js still.

Comment: I need to somehow fit it in my code without messing with the pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Here it works

```
var name;
if(name.checked == true){
 $('#custom-tag').html('HTML');
}else{
 $('#custom-tag').html('DifferentHTML'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = true;  // Your dynamic result True or False is stored in x

if(x)
{
    $('#selector').html();
}
else
{
    $('#selector').html();
}
```

You can also do it by defining var x = ''; in the beginning of script and then depending upon your other script statements, it would get value either true or false. Then you need to check x = '' or not. That's it!

Comment: How do I do this when identifying browses?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){

  $('#in').on('keyup',function(){
    validate();
  });

});

function validate(){
    var x = $('#in').val();
    
  if(x  == "x"){
    $('#result').html('<h3>x entered</h3>');
  }else{
    $('#result').html('<h5>something other than x entered</h5>');
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="in" onChange="validate()"/>

<div id="result">
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: This might work. How do you make it identify if your using chrome?

Comment: This is a  different question and it has answers already:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/29657232/2940051  hope it helps  :)

Comment: @ esteban rincon That may work, but I am still learning JS, so i'm not sure    how to put that in my code.

Comment: change the snippet  I provided, the if(x == "x") to if("/\bCrOS\b/".test(navigator.userAgent)

Comment: Thanks. I added a snippet above in case anyone needed it.

Comment: Your welcome, don't forget to check the answer you think is correct. good luck.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to add it to the code I posted above, so a popup will appear on browsers except chrome. I'm still learning js.

Comment: Yes ofcourse, the  problem is that  I'm from  the  phone right now

Comment: I used your code and I have something that might work, but it's not right now. Not sure how to give it to you.

Comment: I updated the code above. I used yours. I'm missing something in it though.

Comment: Its really hard to help you like this, edit your code.

Comment: It actually works. But each time, you need to type something in. is there a way to make the js run at startup, not until you type?

Comment: Also, I wanted to add all that html in the end of the html part in the snippet if chrome is not identified.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if its chrome this way:

```
if( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1 ){ 
  // chrome, do nothing
} 
else {
  // not chrome put html
  $('#custom-tag').html('HTML');
}
```