# How to detect device is a chromebook in android

Tags: android, chromebook

How to detect device is Chromebook in Android?
The application runs on phone, tablet and Chromebook.
now I need to detect deice is Chromebook.

Answer (score 0):

After going through a good amount of posts this seems like a fairly good solution for detecting the user agent string for Chrome OS with regex.

[Detecting Chrome OS with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657165/detecting-chrome-os-with-javascript)